# How to disable the Ember query parameter router?

Tags: ember.js

I am looking to upgrade Ember for a legacy application that I am supporting. The problem is that Ember's query parameter router is causing application conflicts because the legacy application uses an existing custom query string parser that was written before Ember's implementation was added.

Is there a way to completely disable the Ember query string router so that it will ignore `?` characters in the URL? In a different situation I would simply switch to Ember's query string router, however that is not possible due to the constraints on this release.

Thanks!

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('search', { path: '/search/:query'});
});

App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(urlParams) {
    var queryObj = utils.parseQueryString(urlParams.query);
    App.mainSearcher.setQuery(queryObj.q);
  }
});
```

Comment: Query parameters should not be defined without explicitly being defined in the controller. So you shouldn't need to disable it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something Ember tries to parse everything to the right of a `?` character in the URL which for my application throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: It shouldn't try to look up query parameters unless you specified to use it. I think something else might be causing the error (looks like a call to split a string). Did you check the call stack and the line the error came from?

Comment: Doh. You're correct. However the root cause of the issue is that the `urlParams.query` used to return any value to the right of the route as part of the `params` string. (Given a route of `'/search/:query'`).

Comment: With the new ember search param recognizer if the url is `#/search/q=bike?&sort=score%20desc` then the `urlParams.query` will return `q=bike` because it interprets everything to the right of the query as a search parameter. In my use case the `?` character is a wildcard, and the search should return `bike` or `bikes`. Guess I'll end up accessing the location string directly instead of using the `urlParams` object.

Comment: Turns out it's not quite that simple because the model won't fire between routes where the difference follows the `?` character. The recognizer sees `#/search/q=bike?&sort=score%20desc` and `#/search/q=bike?&sort=id%20desc` as the same route (`#/search/q=bike`). Rolling back to an Ember version before the query params router was added.